# How to get the updated value from the database instead of default value ? - Laravel, Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I've been working on getting the data from mysql database into blade view. So, I've a field "total_sold" in my table. Below is my code

```
public function getDealVersions($dealId)
{
    if ($dealId == "undefined") {
        return array('isVersions' => FALSE);
    }

    $deal = Deal::find($dealId);

    Log::info($deal);

    $return = array(
        'deal' => $deal,
        'isVersions' => count($deal->versions) > 1 ? TRUE : FALSE,
        'versions' => $deal->versions
    );

    return $return;
}
```

In the above code, $deal has the results from the mysql query and the value of total_sold field is 0 which is the default value but the actual value in the database is 2352. Values for all the other fields are returning the expected values except for this field "total_sold". In mysql, for the total_sold field,

```
type=int(11), Default Value = 0 and Nullable=YES
```

So, I'm not able to understand if I should change something with my query or should I change some property in the mysql. Any help or advise is greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: A query will return whats in the row you select, not a default. The default is there so that if you DONT pass a value for that column when you INSERT the row initially, mysql will fit that value in for you.

Comment: Probably just a typo in the question but `Deafult Value` is spelt wrongly

Comment: Every query will return the current value from the database, not the default value. I think you should check your database again, and also check the code which is responsible for updating total_sold.

Comment: I'm not seeing total_sold either in the code you put above. Could you please share where you are setting that and using it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree and this is really confusing me a lot. I should get the whole row but it's just not returning the actual value for total_sold field but the default value

Comment: Maybe you could `dd($return);` and if the error does not jump out at you, post it as part of your question